# Возможно ли в сервере MSSQL поменять формат даты из год-мес-число на число-мес-год?

Tags: sql-server, sql

Возможно ли в сервере MSSQL поменять формат даты из год-мес-число на число-мес-год?

Comment: Что по вашему есть формат??

ИМХО: У даты нет формата - дата это просто дата... Но есть представления, например в виде строки формата ДД/ММ/ГГГГ и etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отображение даты  для клиента определяется языком, с которым соединяется клиент. 
т.е. когда клиент выполняет соединение проверяется 1) язык по умолчанию для клиента. Посмотреть можно либо тупо в менеджере, либо процедурой `sp_helplogins`. Установить можно либо в менеджере, либо через `ALTER LOGIN` 2) если язык для клиента не установлен, выбирается язык по умолчанию, установленный на сервере. Смотреть можно через `sp_reconfigure` или через менеджер

Comment: Работает...Спасибо)))

Comment: Хотя в менеджере всёравно пишет сначала год.....но эт не так важно, главное,когда в запросе пишу, он воспринимает "мой" формат

Answer (score 1):

Да, представление даты можно изменить, я как-то давно имел с этим дело, копайте в сторону `SET DATEFORMAT`. [Доки](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189491.aspx).

Comment: msi был прав, таким образом
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(30), GETDATE(), 105)
получаем ответ 30-01-2012 в 2008R2

Answer (score 1):

Так, например,

```
select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 105)
```

Comment: Я написал select convert(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 105)
язык поставил British (Set language British) читал,что настройки влияют
перезапустил сервер.....
Не работает(((

Comment: SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
тоже поставил.....
Капец....
В чём дело?
Проблема в том, что писать в клиентской проге перевод в этот дибильный формат отображения не хочется, а там везде заносится в виде день-месяц-год